# Java explode method for int array

Tags: java, arrays, int, explode

currently trying to create an explode method for integers similar to php's with no luck because I can't find information on this subject unless it's a string. My end goal is to make (for ex.) 1,2,3 -> 1,1,2,2,3,3

Comment: Explode how many times? two times?

Comment: explode will split by delimiter AFAIU. But you seem to be repeating elements. Please clarify

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php says `explode` splits a string into strings using a delimiter. Can you explain about your input and output

Answer (score 1):

Reading the docs for explode, then this is just `String.split(${regex})`
`"1,2,3".split(",")`

But what you have is not that. I have also produced a solution for that as well.

```
@Test
public void name() {
    int[] result = Arrays.stream(new int[] {1, 2, 3}).flatMap(i -> Arrays.stream(new int[] {i, i})).toArray();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
}
```

`[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]`